# Notification for when laptop lid is closed

Tags: cocoa, sleep, iokit, nsworkspace

Are there any notifications posted when the machine goes to sleep due to the lid being closed? I know of `NSWorkspace`'s sleep notifications, but those are posted regardless of how the machine goes to sleep (even on idle sleep).

Comment: I don't know if this helps in any way, but if you look in IORegistryExplorer, there is an `IOACPIPlatformDevice` object with a name "LID0" below the `AppleACPIPlatformExpert` which acts as provider for an instance of the driver `AppleACPILid`. I don't know if and how you can interface with this; the header for `IOACPIPlatformDevice` is available, the rest is unfortunately closed-source.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can handle the state change by watching for a `kIOPMMessageClamshellStateChange` callback. See ControlPlane's LaptopLidEvidenceSource files for a mostly complete Objective-C code example.

https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane/blob/master/Source/LaptopLidEvidenceSource.h
https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane/blob/master/Source/LaptopLidEvidenceSource.m

Answer (score 0):

are you in Kernel or Userland?
in Kernel-space your Kext can register for PowerManagement events like this:

```
PMinit();
provider->joinPMtree(this);
registerPowerDriver (this, gPowerStates, kPowerNumStates);
```

and then your KEXT can respond to setPowerState() and powerStateDidChangeTo()